# What happens when you run the same command from two screens in unix?

Tags: unix

I needed to remove a fair number of large files from a directory. I used 'rm * ' to remove the files and went to another screen to work on something else. A while later, I used 'rm * ' on the same directory, forgetting that I'd already done that.

I got an error saying "rm: cannot remove `filename': No such file or directory."
Then I went to the first window and there was a similar error.

Are the screens racing to see which finished the rm first? Or does the server thread the processes somehow? How do servers' screens work with one another when they execute the same command on the same directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each case, `rm`ing is just unlinking a directory entry per-file.  The two processes are racing each other but are likely "threaded" together only by context switches from one process to another. If one prepares to unlink a file, then gets context switched out, its competitor will likely get the chance to unlink the same file. Then when the first returns, the file is no longer there, so he moves onto the next entry that is there.

As heximal says, in this case (`rm *`), the asterisk has already been expanded into a list of files, which means that you should, between the two processes, get a full listing that every file you wanted to delete was already gone.

Comment: Oh I see. This goes for other all screen commands too, then? Not just using rm in the same directory.

Comment: Right, even commands executed on the console are multi-tasked with the rest of the system. That usually involves a lot of context switching.

Comment: @Sixthfore: The important thing to recognize is that the wildcard is expanded by *the shell*, not by the program. The programs just see a list of files to process... it doesn't matter if you're running `rm` or `the_most_amazing_program_written_this_millennium`, they both just see a list of files.

Answer (score 1):

the thing is not it executing the same command. actually, nothing crimial happend. `rm` command finishes with error if specified file was not found. when you specify filemask (*) rm starts to delete all files in directory matching that mask. first the process gets a list of files in directory and then fetches this list and performs removing of each file separetely. second rm process which you lauch do absolutely the same. it retrieves list of files and begins to remove them one by one. and there may be the situation when first process removes the file which is in the list of second process. when second process fetch tries to remove that file (that already has been removed) 'No such file or directory' error occures and rm finishes.

Comment: Ah okay. Would you know if this makes executing less efficient or the same?

Comment: there is asbolutely no advantages if you run one rm or two or three